# C# How to send a 1GB file using TCP client

Tags: c#

```
public void SendFile(string remoteHostIP, int remoteHostPort, string longFileName, string shortFileName)
{
    byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(shortFileName);
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(longFileName);
    byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
    byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);
    fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
    fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
    fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
    TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(remoteHostIP, remoteHostPort);
    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    networkStream.Write(clientData, 0, clientData.GetLength(0));
    networkStream.Close();     
}
```

It is possible to use this function to send a 1GB file because the maximum file size i had been try to send now is only up to 400MB. More than that is will cause an error of 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.
When i use another method to split the file into few parts but the server side can't receive the parts continuously and can only receive one of the part.

```
    private void splitBigFile(string FileInputPath, byte[] inputArray)
    {
        int port = 1113;

        double partSize = 104852000;
        int partSize2 = 104852000;

        string FolderOutputPath = "C:\\Users\\xx\\Desktop\\testing split";
        string currPartPath;
        string shortNameSplit;

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FileInputPath, FileMode.Open);
        FileInfo fiSource = new FileInfo(txtFile.Text);
        double sourceLength = fiSource.Length;

        partNum = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(sourceLength / partSize));

        for (int i = 0; i < partNum; i++)
        {
            if (i == (partNum - 1))
            {
                partSize2 = (int)fiSource.Length - (i * 104852000);
            }

            currPartPath = FolderOutputPath + "\\" + fiSource.Name + "." + String.Format(@"{0:D4}", i) + ".part";
            shortNameSplit = fiSource.Name + "." + String.Format(@"{0:D4}", i) + ".part";

            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(shortNameSplit);

            byte[] readStream = new byte[partSize2];

            byte[] concateFile = new byte[5 + fileNameByte.Length];

            int ipSend = ((partNum - 1 - i) << 1);
            ipSend |= 0; // for differentiate ip or file
            byte[] byteSend = new byte[1];
            byteSend[0] = (byte)ipSend;

            fileStream.Read(readStream, 0, partSize2);
            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

            byteSend.CopyTo(concateFile, 0);
            fileNameLen.CopyTo(concateFile, 1);
            fileNameByte.CopyTo(concateFile, 5);
            concateFile.CopyTo(inputArray, 0);
            readStream.CopyTo(inputArray, concateFile.Length);
            string ipAddress = "192.168.43.67";
            int sendport = 1113;
            //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendBigFileSize(ipAddress, sendport, inputArray[i]));
            Array.Clear(readStream, 0, readStream.Length);
            Array.Clear(fileNameLen, 0, fileNameLen.Length);
            Array.Clear(fileNameByte, 0, fileNameByte.Length);
            Array.Clear(byteSend, 0, byteSend.Length);
            Array.Clear(byteSend, 0, byteSend.Length);
        }
        fileStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: One chunk at a time..

Comment: but i try many way the part of the file that i split, at the receive side only can receive once although the client is still continue sending.

Comment: I don't see you trying any way.

Comment: After i split the file into around 100MB for each part, when i send the receiver, it only receive the first part of it

Comment: What is `currPartPath` for?

Comment: to rename the part that i had split

Comment: You don't need to physically split the files into smaller ones, this isn't 1980 and you're not a math teacher turned "programmer" (supposedly). Also `Array.Clear` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, just not all at once. Send chunks at a time.

Besides, the maximum TCP packet size is 64k, and the MTU is 1500 bytes. Your huge buffer is getting split up too, but you're using up a lot of memory doing it. Instead read 32MB (safe HDD I/O buffer size) at a time from your file and send it, then read the next bit.

Comment: Is there any method or sample to use for send as a chunk?

Comment: A `while` loop and `FileStream.Read`.

Comment: ...even a simple `Stream.CopyTo` from the `FileStream` to the `NetworkStream` will do the job perfectly fine. Bonus points for `Stream.CopyToAsync` :-)